# how to handle an empty list, python3

Tags: python, function, if-statement, python-3.x

I have a function that creates a list of aminoacids (aaCandidates), but this list can even be empty. If this list is empty I would like to jump the step and continue with the following one.

My code is:

```
def magicfunction(referenceDistance,referenceAA):

    amminoacids = ('A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V')
    aaCandidates = list()
    for aa in amminoacids:
        if distance(aa,referenceAA) == referenceDistance:
            aaCandidates.append(aa)
        if not aaCandidates:
            break

    luckyAA = choice(aaCandidates)

    return(luckyAA)
```

I call this function in another file as follow:

```
for i in range(lenghtPairs):
    r1 = randrange(20)
    r2 = randrange(20)
    coppie.append([aminoacidi[r1], aminoacidi[r2]])

for i in range(lenghtPairs):
    dictionary = dict()
    frequenze = dict()

    if i == 0:
        a = randrange(20)
        b = randrange(20)
        pairs[0] = [aminoacids[a], aminoacids[b]]
    else:
        c = randrange(20)
        pairs[i][0] = aminoacids[c]
        distanceNeighbours = distance(pairs[i][0],pairs[i-1][0])
        aaChosen = magicfunction(distanceNeighbours,pairs[i-1][1])
        pairs[i][1] = aaChosen

    print(i + 1)
```

I tried the condition => `if not aaCandidates: break` but it didn't work:

```
      File "/.../lib/python3.4/random.py", line 255, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Comment: Define *didn't work* more closely. You mean the `random.choice()` call raises an exception?

Comment: Note that it is far more common (and natural) to use `[]` to define an empty list, and `{}` for an empty dictionary, rather than `list()` and `dict()`.

Comment: if "len(aaCandidates) == 0"?

Comment: @en_Knight: why would that work when `not aaCandidates` didn't? Something *else* is wrong.

Comment: Note that `if not aaCandidates:` `break` will _immediately_ break out of the `for` loop if the first `aa` in `amminoacids` doesn't get appended to `aaCandidates`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right, it almost definitely wouldn't, unless, like, she's overwritten the list class to do something weird. If she had imported numpy array as list, then "not mylist" would throw an exception (for a non-trivial list) where len(mylist) == 0 wouldn't... but that's probably not the case

Comment: My error tells "Cannot choose from an empty sequence" so I think that it doesn't understand the way I'm telling him "if not aaCandidates: break"

thank you for the note about empty list and empty dictionary :)

Comment: @laura: then don't use `random.choice()` on the empty list. What should be returned instead when the final list is empty?

Comment: Seems like your condition is in the wrong place

Comment: @laura: or perhaps you wanted to signal an error if there are no candidates?

Comment: @en_Knight: the condition was just in the wrong place; there is little point in breaking out of the loop here when the first `aa` values is not a candidate.

Comment: @Martijn no no I didn't want to signal the error I just wanted the program to continue with the following iteration without considering the step with the empty list.

Comment: @laura: then you need to use `continue` in your *other* code; have `magicfunction` return `None` if there are no choices and use `if not aaChosen: continue` in the part that uses the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is empty, so `random.choice()` fails. You'll need to decide what to do *instead* when the list is empty, but do so *outside* of the `for` loop, so when the list has completed building:

```
for aa in amminoacids:
    if distance(aa,referenceAA) == referenceDistance:
        aaCandidates.append(aa)

if not aaCandidates:
    return 'some default choice'

luckyAA = choice(aaCandidates)
return luckyAA
```

All that putting your `break` in the loop achieves is to ensure that nothing is going to be added to your list if the first `aa` was not a candidate.

Comment: Or: `return heapq.nlargest(1, (aa for aa in amminoacids if distance(aa, referenceAA) == referenceDistance), key=lambda L: random.random()) or 'default')` ?

Comment: @JonClements: yay, lets go find some more ultra-advanced one-liners! :-P